# Como hacer un contador que aumente si no se encuentra una letra en una palabra :AVA

Tags: java, ciclos

Buenas tardes! Mi problema es este, intente realizar un bucle `for` para que me recorriera letra por letra una palabra, y al no encontrarla, que el contador aumente en uno y mi problema es que en el momento de recorrer toda la palabra aumento por uno por cada ves que no aparezca la palabra....

Aquí dejo el pedazo de código por si no me di a entender bien...

```
primerJugador = jugador1.getText();
       comparacion1 = primerJugador.charAt(0);

       for (int i=0;i<palabra.length();i++) {
        comparacion2 = palabra.charAt(i);
           if (comparacion1==comparacion2) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letra "+comparacion1 + " encontrada");
               encontrado = true;
           }
           else{
               encontrado = false;
           }
        }

       if(encontrado)
       {
            contador = contador+1;
       }
```

El programa recorre todas las letras y va sumando el `contador` las veces que no lo encuentre.

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco mejor el problema? Dada una palabra quieres ver cuantas letras coinciden respecto a otra palabra?

Comment: No, lo que quería decir por ejemplo: 
No se encuentra la palabra, el contador aumenta. Si esta en 0 ahora se vuelve 1, se realiza la comparación otra ves y no se vuelve a encontrar la letra, ahora el contador aumenta y se vuelve en 2, eso es lo que no logro hacer...

El programa recorre todas las letras y va sumando el contador las veces que no lo encuentre, por ejemplo pongo "hola" y escribo la letra "t" el contador se me vuelve 5 en ves de 1..

Comment: En tu ejemplo usas palabra.length(), pero la variable __palabra__ no esta, en el ejemplo.

Comment: Por favor, vuelve a editar tu pregunta clarificando el problema y agregando ejemplos.

Comment: El if(encontrado) tiene que estar dentro del for, para que incremente en cada iteración.

Comment: Comentas que contador inicia en 0,  entonces esto no concuerda con lo que comentas: "El programa recorre todas las letras y va sumando el contador las veces que no lo encuentre, por ejemplo pongo "hola" y escribo la letra "t" el contador se me vuelve 5 en ves de 1", ¿contador es inicializado en 0 o en 1?

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente agrega la variable para el contador en el `else`, que es donde entraría si no encuentra la palabra:

```
        for (int i=0;i<palabra.length();i++) {
           comparacion2 = palabra.charAt(i);
           if (comparacion1==comparacion2) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letra "+comparacion1 + " encontrada");
               encontrado = true;               
           }else{
               contador++;
               encontrado = false;
           }
        }

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contador  "+contador + ", ¿se encontro? " + encontrado);
```

Cabe destacar que si la variable contador es inicializada en 0, si `palabra = "hola"` y escribes "t" que sería la comparación, obtendrás como resultado el valor de la variable `contador` 4, que son las ocasiones que no encontró la letra "t" en la palabra, la variable `encontrado` tendrá valor `false`.

Si `palabra = "hola"` y escribes "a", el `contador` obviamente tendrá un valor de 3, que son las ocasiones que no encontró la letra "a", y la variable `encontrado` tendrá valor `true`.

---

Agrego una [**demo online**](https://ideone.com/d44zQJ) para ver lo que comento.

Comment: Me parece que lo que busca es algo tipo ahorcado, donde cuente la cantidad de fallos, no la cantidad de veces que no esta la letra. o sea, que deberia estar despues del if? igual sigue estando confusa la cosa

Comment: @gbianchi sinceramente no lo había pensado, pero es verdad posiblemente sería un juego "ahorcado". "ahorcado inverso"? :P